# Ubuntu won’t start

Tags: boot, startup

I have no idea what happened. Yesterday I closed my computer and went to bed, today it didn’t have battery so I plugged it in and is stuck in some screen I’ve never seen. The screen shows a bunch of starting and started processes and thats it. Any idea what to do? I have been waiting a while to see if it will finish but nothing happens.

Comment: I unplugged and plugged it again and the next ACPI error appears “Thread 894394112 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 901689216 (20190703/exmutex-382)” “Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER) (20190703/psparse-531)”

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1250651/edit) instead of commenting upon your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a difficult one to solve with just the info you gave. There are a number of steps you can take in order to find out where the problem lies. Step 1 is usually to test the GRUB bootloader. If it works, you can boot into recovery mode and test things out. You may need to reinstall your system. This doesn't necessarily mean you've lost your files. There's a pretty good [walkthrough](https://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/) guide to testing GRUB, recovery mode and reinstalling Ubuntu that you may want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed to solve it. It was because the root partition didn't have space left.
To solve that in the grub menu I chose the Advanced Options, then the recover mode and then the option to free some space. After that I was able to start Ubuntu as usual.
I made sure to free some more space after that so it doesn't happen again.